# Adaptação de colunas csv com campos DB que não seja hard code?

Tags: banco-de-dados, python-3.x, csv

Boom dia :)

Estou fazendo em python um script que lê um arquivo .csv que pega algumas colunas (não são todas as colunas, apenas algumas) e salva no banco de dados.
Como as colunas do csv e o nome dos Campos do banco não são os mesmos, queria saber se existe alguma forma mais inteligente de fazer a adaptação dos nomes que não seja "hard code".

Ou seja, minha função lê o arquivo csv, por enquanto estou ignorando a primeira linha com `next()` já que os nomes do head não é o msm no banco. Na passagem de linha estou pegando umas colunas específicas. Por exemplo tem uns csvs com 10 campos e eu pego uns 5 apenas.
Daí trato esses campos e já jogo numa string `SQL` e todo pra salvar no banco.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
Colunas = "nome, idade, sexo, signo, asc" 

Valores = "'{}', {}, '{}', '{}', '{}'".format(row[2], row[3], row[5], row[7], row[10])
```

Então tenho que dá um `"insert into tb_x ({colunas}) values ({valores})".`

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o dicionário `coluna` onde a chave é o nome do campo e o valor seria a coluna desejada. Depois no `insert` você usa `colunas.get("nome")` por exemplo.

```
colunas = {"nome":row[2], "idade":row[3], "sexo":row[5], "signo":row[7], "asc":row[10]}

valores = "'{}', {}, '{}', '{}', '{}'".format(colunas.get("nome"), colunas.get("idade"), colunas.get("sexo"), colunas.get("signo"), colunas.get("asc"))
```